# Items in Plones TinyMCE content browser are overlayed in album view - how to tackle this?

Tags: tinymce, plone, plone-4.x

I do not know if this is a bug or rather stems from any customizations. I would like to know how to tackle this problem:

If I click on "add image" or "Link" in Plone's "Content Browser" the default view mode is "Album". In this mode the items are layed above each other, i.e. after 4 items the next items do not seem to be put into a new column.

See the screenshot:
[image]

Plone version is 4.3.2. How can I fix this? Pointers (relevant files, parts of code) welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have seen this happen too, depending on what I did with styling and skins.  TinyMCE uses a grid system for showing these images and this needs the columns.css file from plonetheme.sunburst.  I only now realize that this actually already goes wrong in the way you describe when you use standard Plone 4.3.2 and choose the classic theme as skin.

Ah, but it only fails because there is a typo in the columns.css that is shipped with plonetheme.classic, which actually includes the grid css as well.  You can customize this file in portal_skins and fix the error.  The problem is a line that is meant as a comment.

Change this line:

`The 16-column Deco Grid System.`

into this line:

`/* The 16-column Deco Grid System.`

Comment: Thanks, works now (you were right, I had classic theme). As this is a bug, would you mind submitting a report and patch for this? Or shall I rather?

Comment: ok, I see you already [did](https://github.com/plone/plonetheme.classic/commit/ebf6dd27ddd3a9b2e062a1e896d5bbe05c8ba835)

Comment: Thanks for investigation and fixing!